# Process for changing database passwords and avoiding website downtime

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, security

The boss says we need to change our SQL Server account passwords more often than, well, never at all. He decided this yesterday after we discovered that one of our web.config files may have been compromised just over a month ago. It contained credentials for three databases, and all three passwords were several years old (judging by the year contained in the password).

So if I have two different DBAs to deal with, each requiring a time-consuming  ticket process to change a password, and a web server manager who requires a similar time-consuming process, there seems to be no way to change all three SQL Server account passwords without a significant amount of downtime before I can update my site's web.config. And he wants us to do this every 3 months now.

So I suggested to the DBAs that we should have two accounts for each database in this example, one active and one disabled 99% of the time. Then every 3 months, for each database, I could request that the DBAs enable the alternate accounts and give them fresh passwords. Then I could request a web.config update pointing to the fresh accounts. Once the website is updated, then the DBAs could disable the three accounts that are no longer in use.

Is this a common practice? Is there a term for it? Is there a better idea? Because this idea got some push-back here. And lastly, why doesn't SQL Server (or any similar technologies) optionally allow an old password to live on for a short time, like an hour perhaps, after an account password has been changed, to help in this scenario where we want to avoid downtime?

Thanks for getting this far!

Comment: Do whatever works best for your team.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! While the change process needs to differentiate critical changes from maintenance and development changes, having in place a backup account is brilliant for mitigating disasters.

Comment: I would find out how important the business considers its data on your systems and argue your case in a perspective that helps your bosses look good. Wish i had time to answer all yout questions more fully.

Comment: if the dba's or other support staff are giving you are hard-time, escalate to your boss, who should then escalate as needed to the support folks supervisors. they will work something out. this is not a technical matter, but something that needs to be worked out with conversation

Comment: Thanks all! This is definitely going to take some tact, but its not as bad as I made it sound!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this recently via the following sequence.

1. Transition all permissions granted to individual logins/users to be role based (detailed below).
2. Create a second login/user (as you suggest) with a different password than the first; add them to that role.
3. Have your application transition to the second login.
4. Verify that you don't see any login events for the first login.
5. Change the password for the first login (or drop it entirely if you want to keep your security surface area as small as possible).

As for the "create a role and transition the permissions to it" bit, here's the script I used:

---

```
declare @user sysname = '<your user here>',
    @role sysname = '<your role here>';

-- no changes should be necessary below here

select concat('CREATE ROLE ', quotename(@role), ' AUTHORIZATION [dbo];') AS [grant], '' AS [revoke], '' AS [permission_name], NULL AS [class_desc]
union all
select concat('ALTER ROLE ', quotename(@role), ' ADD MEMBER ', QUOTENAME(@user), ';'), '', '', null
UNION all
select concat('GRANT ', permission_name collate database_default, ' ON ',

        CASE class_desc
            when 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' then 'OBJECT::'
            when 'TYPE' then 'TYPE::'
        END,

    QUOTENAME(
    CASE class_desc
            when 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' then OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(major_id)
            when 'TYPE' then (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) FROM sys.[types] WHERE [user_type_id] = [major_id])
    END), '.',

    quotename(
        CASE class_desc
            when 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' then object_name(major_id)
            when 'TYPE' then TYPE_NAME(major_id)
        END
    ),
    ' TO ', QUOTENAME(@role), ';'
), 

CONCAT('REVOKE ', permission_name collate database_default, ' ON ',

        CASE class_desc
            when 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' then 'OBJECT::'
            when 'TYPE' then 'TYPE::'
        END,

    QUOTENAME(
    CASE class_desc
            when 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' then OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(major_id)
            when 'TYPE' then (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) FROM sys.[types] WHERE [user_type_id] = [major_id])
    END), '.',

    quotename(
        CASE class_desc
            when 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' then object_name(major_id)
            when 'TYPE' then TYPE_NAME(major_id)
        END
    ),
    ' FROM ', QUOTENAME(@user), ';'
), [permission_name], [class_desc]
from sys.database_permissions
where grantee_principal_id = user_id(@user)
    AND [permission_name] <> 'CONNECT'
ORDER BY [permission_name];
```

---

In my case, I only had to worry about object and user-defined type permissions; if you have more than that, you'll have to account for them. But the above will generate a result set with four column. The `grant` column will be the SQL to create the role, add the user you specify to the role, and then grant the role all the permissions that the user currently has. The `revoke` column will be the SQL to take those same permissions away from the user. The other two columns were there just for my sanity as I was developing the script to make sure I didn't miss anything.

Once you run all of the above (please test it in a non-production environment before going to production!), your application will be leveraging the role to get 
its permissions. After which you should be able to move forward with the rest of the plan detailed above with confidence and at a cadence that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! That's very helpful because as you probably guessed, the dba who didn't like the idea inherited a database with no roles and very complicated user permissions. The account I asked him to duplicate returned 600+ rows with your query here, and that's just one of the databases it is mapped to. I'm not even sure he knows who and what all is using this account so it's going to be a big ordeal, but no question it needs reorganized and hopefully this will go a long way towards making the case and ultimately following the outlined sequence. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing! What's nice about the query above is that it shows all the permissions explicitly granted to that user. So the creation of a role with those same permissions is just one step away. After which you can get rid of those explicitly granted permissions. You'll get there!

Answer (score 0):

> web.config files may have been compromised just over a month ago

That seems to be the root of the issue so IMHO that's the *primary* issue that should be resolved (even if recycling pwds makes all the sense - it's low hanging fruit in comparison).

Suggestion would be to [employ encryption for sensitive `web.config` sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68ze1hb2.aspx) to mitigate such.

Hth.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Backstory: A security audit in April spotted a download url that was vulnerable to path traversal. Coincidentally, I implement my new version of the site a week later, which had no such vulnerability. 6 weeks later, they called asking why they can’t download our web.config file anymore, and that was the first we heard about it! Anyway, encryption would have helped mitigate worry in this case, for sure. But as I understand it (and I haven’t read too deeply yet) , this will only obscure the password for anyone with access to my PC or the web server, correct?